# Iterate over data() returned value

Tags: loops, vuejs2

My HTML code is like below

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in values">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

My vue.js code is like below

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                values: {}
            }
        },
        props: ['applicants', 'pageinfo'],
        watch: {
            applicants (val) {
                EventBus.$on('click',  function (skillName) {
                    this.values = val[0];   
                    console.log(this.values);  // I am getting output here.
                });
            },
        },
    }
```

I am trying to iterate over the values of `val[0]`. But I am not getting any output.

Comment: `values` is not an array, its an object

Comment: Thanks @RishikeshDhokare for your reply. Should I use `return {
                values: []
            }` ?

Comment: yeah, what i meant was values should be an array. you can try using that.

Comment: Thanks @RishikeshDhokare. But it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: whats the value of val[0]?

Comment: Thanks @FarazShuja. I edited the question. That will be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either use arrow function like

```
applicants (val) {
    EventBus.$on('click',  (skillName) => {
        this.values = val[0];   
        console.log(this.values);  // I am getting output here.
    });
},
```

or save the reference of this before the event handler

```
applicants (val) {
    var _self = this;
    EventBus.$on('click',  function (skillName) {
        _self.values = val[0];   
        console.log(this.values);  // I am getting output here.
    });
},
```